# Update only dynamically chosen columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I've created a function `copy_rows_from_table(_tbl regclass)` which copies records in a table and gives them a new primary key value. It returns a hstore containing pairs of old_id => new_id. For example for table `books` my function would create two additional records and return a hstore.

`books` initially:

```
  id | title         | price | author_id | publisher_id 
 ----+---------------+-------+-----------+--------------
   1 | The Cyberiad  | 15.00 |    23     |      46
   2 |   The Trial   | 10.00 |    12     |      67
```

`books` after evaluation of `copy_rows_from_table('books')`:

```
  id | title         | price | author_id | publisher_id 
 ----+---------------+-------+-----------+--------------
   1 | The Cyberiad  | 15.00 |    23     |      46
   2 |   The Trial   | 10.00 |    12     |      67
   3 | The Cyberiad  | 15.00 |    23     |      46
   4 |   The Trial   | 10.00 |    12     |      67
```

returned hstore:
`"1"=>"3", "2"=>"4"`

It works fine. Now I would like to create a function that copies records from a few tables (passed in an array) and then updates all foreign keys using returned hstore. For example after copying `books` and `authors` I want `author_id` column to be updated in `books` table. After using my function on `books`, `authors` and `publishers`, if I had a hstore which contains `"1"=>"3", "2"=>"4","23"=>"167","12"=>"98","46"=>"87","67"=>"102"`, my function should update `books` table in this way:

```
  id | title         | price | author_id | publisher_id 
 ----+---------------+-------+-----------+--------------
   1 | The Cyberiad  | 15.00 |    23     |      46
   2 |   The Trial   | 10.00 |    12     |      67
   3 | The Cyberiad  | 15.00 |    167    |      87
   4 |   The Trial   | 10.00 |    98     |      102
```

I came up with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_tables(_tbls regclass[])
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
  _tbl regclass;
  _id_pairs hstore;
  _table_id_pairs hstore;
  _row record;
BEGIN
  FOR _tbl IN SELECT _tbls
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT copy_rows_from_table(''%1$s'')', _tbl)
    INTO _table_id_pairs;
    SELECT COALESCE(_id_pairs, hstore('')) || COALESCE(_table_id_pairs, hstore('')) INTO _id_pairs;
  END LOOP;

  FOR _tbl IN SELECT _tbls
  LOOP
    FOR _row IN EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %1$s WHERE id = ANY(''%2$s''::uuid[])', _tbl, avals(_id_pairs))
    LOOP
      EXECUTE (
        SELECT format('UPDATE %1$s SET (%2$s) = (%3$s) WHERE id = %4$s'
                    , _tbl, string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', '),
                    string_agg(COALESCE(_id_pairs -> ('_row.' || quote_ident(attname)), '_row.' || quote_ident(attname)), ', '), _row.id)
        FROM   pg_attribute
        WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
        AND    NOT attisdropped
        AND    attnum > 0
        AND    attname LIKE '%_id'
      );
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it doesn't quite work. Is there any possibility to update records in a way I explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do it in PLpgSQL. I just iterate through every column of every record. Here is my working function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_tables(_tbls regclass[])
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
  _id_pairs hstore;
  _table_id_pairs hstore;
  _row record;
  _hs_row record;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN array_lower(_tbls, 1)..array_upper(_tbls, 1)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT copy_rows_from_table(''%1$s'')', _tbls[I])
    INTO _table_id_pairs;
    SELECT COALESCE(_id_pairs, hstore('')) || COALESCE(_table_id_pairs, hstore('')) INTO _id_pairs;
  END LOOP;

  FOR I IN array_lower(_tbls, 1)..array_upper(_tbls, 1)
  LOOP
    FOR _row IN EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %1$s WHERE id = ANY(''%2$s''::uuid[])', _tbls[I], avals(_id_pairs))
    LOOP
      FOR _hs_row IN SELECT kv."key", kv."value" FROM each(hstore(_row)) kv
      LOOP
        IF _hs_row."value" = ANY(akeys(_id_pairs)) THEN
          EXECUTE format('UPDATE %1$s SET %2$s = ''%3$s'' WHERE id = ''%4$s''',
                          _tbls[I], _hs_row."key", _id_pairs -> _hs_row."value", _row.id);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

PLpgSQL isn't good tool for dynamic updates. Probably there are some few others possibilities, but no one is trivial. The other ways:

1. Using some more dynamic PL language - PLPythonu, PLPerl
2. Using extension   https://github.com/okbob/pltoolbox - there are functions `record_get_fields` and `record_set_fields`